# Mail.app : What do the padlock icons mean?

Tags: mail.app, email, encryption

If I encrypt an email with S/MIME an icon showing a CLOSED padlock is displayed under "Security". However, if I encrypt using OpenPGP it's an OPEN padlock icon. Both are followed by the word "Encrypted" though.

Why the two icons / What's the difference?

Comment: Open is not encrypted.

Comment: @Buscar웃 That's not true. In the case of OpenPGP an **open** padlock means that an email has been decrypted and it's readable. Why the difference with S/MIME I don't know.

Comment: @Thecafremo Standard Icon is closed padlock (if using Signature with Certificate) so my guess is Open means something else.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I tested it this morning, and it works as I said. If you receive an email, encrypted with *OpenPGP* and you read it (you enter the correct passphrase an it *stores* it), the padlock displayed is *open* and the word *Encrypted* is by it side.